# Web application using Spring and maven doesn't work

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, servlets

I am new using Spring and I tried to create a project that prints hello when I put the following path in the browser: http://localhost:8080/FirstApp/hello but it doesn't work. The browser shows this:

[image]

If I put http://localhost:8080/FirstApp/ I can see this

[image]

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"    
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>FirstApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>FirstApp</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.3.2.RELEASE</version>
</parent>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>7.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>  
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.7</source>
                <target>1.7</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>7.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee 
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd"
 version="2.4">

<display-name>Spring MVC Application</display-name>

<servlet>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>
     org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet
  </servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
```

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.jsp</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>  
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>  
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-servlet.xml</param-value>  
  </context-param>  
<listener>
    <listener-class>
       org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
    </listener-class>
</listener>
```

My spring-servlet.xml (i know i have here more things than I need, have to delete some but I start adding to see if this was the problem but not):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:c="http://www.springframework.org/schema/c"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:flow="http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config"
   xmlns:jee="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee"
   xmlns:jms="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms"
   xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"  
   xmlns:lang="http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang"
   xmlns:osgi="http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"

   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config http://www.springframework.org/schema/webflow-config/spring-webflow-config-2.0.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee http://www.springframework.org/schema/jee/spring-jee-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms http://www.springframework.org/schema/jms/spring-jms-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang http://www.springframework.org/schema/lang/spring-lang-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi http://www.springframework.org/schema/osgi/spring-osgi-1.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/util http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-4.2.xsd
      http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd">
<mvc:annotation-driven></mvc:annotation-driven>  
<context:component-scan base-package="com.mycompany.firstapp" />
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
</beans>
```

My hello.jsp

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<title>Hello World</title>
</head>
<body>
   <h2>${message}</h2>
</body>
```

And finally my Hello.java:

```
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
//@ComponentScan
public class Hello {
   @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
   public String printHello() {
      return "hello";
   }
}
```

Here is my project structure(netbeans):

[image]

I don't know what I have wrong. I just want to "call" the java function and show it in the path  http://localhost:8080/FirstApp/hello.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: How about creating an index page and then invoking your path 'url' from index page.

Comment: it would work if you requested `http://localhist:8080/FirstApp/hello.jsp`  You have to read about Dispatcher Servlet in MVC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your `servlet-mapping` configuration is not correct. Try changing it to the following

```
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>spring</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Also, looking at

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
  <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/" />
  <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
</bean>
```

your `jsp` directory should be under `/WEB-INF/`.

Then try to access `http://localhost:8080/FirstApp/hello`

Comment: Glad you got it working :) Mark this answer as a solution if possible please